# Can I use RShiny to open RMarkdown Files?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

Is there a way I can embed RMarkdown documents in an RShiny app? That way when someone clicks on the document it opens in a new window? I know it's straightforward to embed RShiny into RMarkdown documents, but does it go the other way?

I'm working in a RShiny Dashboard, and I'd like to be able to open my menuSubItem and have the list of Rmds there.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "MWE"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("folder-open"),
           menuSubItem("Sub Menu 1",icon = icon("folder-open"), tabName = "subMenu1")
  )
)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "subMenu1",
            h2("How do I list RMarkdown files here?")
     )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you want to show the actual markdown documents where people can edit the code, or do you just want to show a rendered markdown document? For the latter, you could probably link to rendered html documents

Comment: Perhaps this can help : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to show the markdown documents where people can edit the code.